# The exe file of python app creates the database but doesn't create tables in some PCs

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyinstaller

I have implemented an application using **python, PostgreSQL, pyqt5, Sqlalchemy** and made an execution file for it through **pyInstaller**.

I tried installing this app on some laptops which had PostgreSQL 13 installed already on them. But there is a problem.

In some Laptops it's Ok and everything runs successfully and the database is created along with its tables on PostgreSQL, we can check it through Pgadmin 4 and we can work with the application successfully, but in some other laptops **the database is created but not its tables and so the console stops and nothing appears** and when we check Pgadmin there only is the database name not its tables.

P.S: the systems are Windows 10 and Windows 7.

I have no idea what to check or what to do I would appreciate it if anyone can give me any ideas.

the following code is base.py:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
    from sqlalchemy import Column
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5432/db23')
    if not database_exists(engine.url):
        create_database(engine.url)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Base = declarative_base()
```

and the following function is called in initializer function of the app:

```
    def the_first_time_caller(self):
        session = Session()
        # 2 - generate database schema
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # create tables in the database
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

with Updating Python and downgrading Sqlalchemy, It runs successfully now.